# Android Navigation add to back stack

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-navigation

I tried use Android Navigation component and have a problem with back stack.

I have Fragment A, B.To navigate from A to B, I write:

```
Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.a_to_b)
```

But how can i return back to A on back button clicked?

Comment: You can [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59834683/4390987)

Comment: If you press the back button on android It should get handled automatically and should goes back to previous visible fragment. Do you want to override that behavior?

Comment: if i click the back button on android nothing happens. Actualy it just refresh the current fragment

Answer (score 2):

It's well known that the Nav library is supposed to take care of pushing and popping from the backstack itself. I've spent a couple of hours hunting a missing line though so thought this might help future googlers, from [the basic sample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationBasicSample):

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
android:id="@+id/nav_host_splash_fragment"
android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:defaultNavHost="true"
app:navGraph="@navigation/launch_nav_graph"
tools:context=".launch.SplashActivity" />
```

If you **do not** set the `defaultNavHost`, you basically need to take care of the backstack yourself. This line is crucial to automatically add fragments to the back stack.

Answer (score 0):

The fragment A is in your **backstack**, so you can just implement a *click listener* for your button and, for example, use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54522734/4251242).

It provides an example and some explanations:

> New release [androidx.activity ver. 1.0.0-alpha07](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity#1.0.0-alpha07) brings some
>   changes
>
> More explanations in android official guide: [Provide custom back
>   navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back) ```java public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
>
> ```
> @Override
> public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>
>     // This callback will only be called when MyFragment is at least Started.
>     OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true /* enabled by default */) {
>         @Override
>         public void handleOnBackPressed() {
>             // Handle the back button event
>         }
>     };
>     requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, callback);
> ```

Happy coding!