# Android Navigation-Component: Back Button not navigating back to viewpager2

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I have a **Button** in my viewpager2 (Page: `UserDataFragment`) which navigates the user to another screen (`UserDataChangeEmailFragment`), where they can change their password etc. The problem I encounter is that the back button on this screen is not working (e.g when the user presses back and or the toolbar button, the user is not navigated back to `UserDataFragment`).

The only error I then get is: `SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length`.

### Graph Picture (trying to navigate from x to y):

[image]

### Graph Structure

```
UserDataHolderFragment (Holder for the ViewPager2)
 |
 |--UserDataFragment (First Page of the ViewPager2, here is the **Button**)
 |  |
 |  |-- UserDataChangeEmailFragment (Back button not working) 
 |
 |
 |--UserDataAddressFragment (Second Page of the ViewPager2)
```

### Graph Code (Deleted unnecessary stuff)

```
<navigation android:id="@+id/nav_user_data"
    app:startDestination="@id/userDataHolderFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/userDataHolderFragment"
        android:name="com.rsb3000.app.framework.ui.view.fragment.user.loggedIn.userdata.UserDataHolderFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_user_data_holder" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_userDataHolderFragment_to_userDataChangeEmailFragment"
            app:destination="@id/userDataChangeEmailFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_userDataHolderFragment_to_userDataChangePasswordFragment"
            app:destination="@id/userDataChangePasswordFragment" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/userDataFragment"
        android:name="com.rsb3000.app.framework.ui.view.fragment.user.loggedIn.userdata.UserDataFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_user_data">
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/userDataAddressFragment"
        android:name="com.rsb3000.app.framework.ui.view.fragment.user.loggedIn.userdata.UserDataAddressFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_user_data_address" >
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/userDataChangeEmailFragment"
        android:name="com.rsb3000.app.framework.ui.view.fragment.user.loggedIn.userdata.UserDataChangeEmailFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_user_data_change_email" />

</navigation>
```

### UserDataHolderFragment Code (Navigation button here)

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class UserDataHolderFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_user_data_holder) {
    private val binding: FragmentUserDataHolderBinding by viewBinding(FragmentUserDataHolderBinding::bind)

    val userDataViewPagerAdapter: UserDataViewPagerAdapter get() = UserDataViewPagerAdapter(SnackbarUtils(), this)
    @Inject lateinit var tabLayoutHelper: TabLayoutHelper

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.headline.userStandardToolbar.setupWithNavController(findNavController(), AppBarConfiguration(findNavController().graph))
        bindObjects()
        bindTablayout()
    }

    private fun bindObjects() {
        with(binding) {
            lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
            vpUserData.adapter = userDataViewPagerAdapter
        }
    }

    private fun bindTablayout() {
        tabLayoutHelper.init(binding.tlUserData, binding.vpUserData) { tab, position ->
            when(position) {
                0 -> tab.text = requireContext().getString(R.string.fragment_user_data_holder_user_data_tab)
                1 -> tab.text = requireContext().getString(R.string.fragment_user_data_holder_user_address_tab)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        tabLayoutHelper.onDestroyView()
        binding.vpUserData.adapter = null
    }
}
```

### UserDataFragment

```
private fun bindBtnClicks() {
   btnGoToChangeAddress.setOnClickListener {
       findNavController().navigate(
          UserDataHolderFragmentDirections.actionUserDataFragmentHolderToUserDataChangeEmailFragment()
      )
   }
}
```

### UserDataChangeEmailFragment (BACK BUTTON NOT WORKING HERE)

```
class UserDataChangeEmailFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_user_data_change_email) {
    private val binding: FragmentUserDataChangeEmailBinding by viewBinding(FragmentUserDataChangeEmailBinding::bind)

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.headline.userStandardToolbar.setupWithNavController(findNavController(), AppBarConfiguration(findNavController().graph))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've solved my error. This had nothing to do with my nav_graph nor the code in the fragment. The problem was that I navigated to the other fragment within the livedata. Clicking the back button immediately triggered the observation of the livedata and navigated me again and again.

Solution: Before navigating, reset the livedata. You can see more solutions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59834398/android-navigation-component-back-button-not-working) stackoverflow post